# Деплой проекта ror с одного сервера на другой

Tags: сервер, ruby-on-rails, ruby, развертывание, capistrano

У меня есть, так скажем, только бэкап проекта на руби с одного сервера. Структура там такая: deploy/projectname -> внутри releases, repo, shared. Я сталкиваюсь с этим в первый раз и не знаю, каким образом вот этот проект перенести на другой сервер. Совсем.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас не совсем бэкап, это просто каталог приложения, заполненный capistrano. Вам нужно для начала получить исходный код, репозиторий прописан в фалйе /config/deploy.rb Разворачиваете у себя проект, настраиваете, ознакамливатесь. Потом настраиваете деплоймент через capistrano, информации валом, плюс уже есть конфиги. Что именно надо сделать -- не видя исходного кода сказать нельзя.

Comment: Спасибо, да,это я понимаю. А оттуда можно будет стянуть данные с бд хотя бы? Но тут такое дело,что мне не могут передоставить доступ к репозиторию, где находился проект. Типо исходи из чего есть.

Comment: Тогда смотрите в папке releases последний по дате. Это вот и будет ваш исходный код. Данных у вас не будет скорее всего (если только проект не использовал sqlite, тогда база должна лежать где-то рядом) . Поищите, там где-то должен быть database.yml, будете знать, что за СУБД была на сервере.